# how to check the value in SSRS automatically based on other parameter values?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, msbi

I want the parameter value to be checked automatically in the second dropdown based on the selection of first parameter value.

For e.g In the below image i am selecting the Finops in the first dropdown so in second dropdown it should checked automatically.

Can anyone please guide?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you want to create is also known as **cascaded parameters** in SSRS world.

Set the default parameter to whatever value you want to see like below:

[image]

Just make sure whatever value you are adding as default value is also present in the set of *Available Values*.